# Table - Replace values of a column

Tags: table

I have several tables (tab separated) in which the first column is as follow:

```
MONTH
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

I would like to replace those values by the actual month value, as follow:

```
MONTH
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` to replace the first field with the "line number-1" would work for your example case

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t" ; OFS="\t" } NR>1 { $1=NR-1} { print}'
```

e.g.

```
$ cat x
MONTH   DATA
0.00    something
0.00    data
0.00    here
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah
0.00    blah

$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t" ; OFS="\t" } NR>1 { $1=NR-1} { print}' x
MONTH   DATA
1       something
2       data
3       here
4       blah
5       blah
6       blah
7       blah
8       blah
9       blah
10      blah
11      blah
12      blah
```